# Open in VS code Jupyter Notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have an issue that I cannot solve. Im trying to open a big file in VS Code [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Yjy.png) ,but when Im trying to open with the option: **Jupyter:Open Jupyter Notebook** nothing happens.

With others files works fine and opens in jupyter notebook automatically but not this one. I think maybe I touch something so now it doesn't work.

Could somebody help me please?

Comment: Could you open it in the browser?

Comment: hi! how could I check that?

Comment: In terminal type "jupyter notebook" or "jupyter lab" and hit Enter.